# No overload for method 'DisplayOutput' takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, methods, call

I am trying to code a simple program to calculate netpay for employees. As far as I know my code is solid with the exception of my method call to DisplayOutput(); 
I understand what the error means but I do not understand how fix it to compile.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Project02CoddR
{
    class NetPayApp
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            Console.Clear();
            DisplayTitle();
            InputData();
            DisplayOutput();
            TerminateProgram();

        }

        public static void DisplayTitle()
        {

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("\tProject 02 - Net Pay Calculator - ");
            Console.WriteLine();
            DrawLine();

        }

        public static void InputData()
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Please enter the number of hours worked this week: ");
            int hoursWorked = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Please enter your hourly rate of pay <e.g. 9.35>: ");
            double payRate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Please enter your number of dependants: ");
            int dependants = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("\n\tAre you a salesperson? <Y or N>: ");
            string aValue = Console.ReadLine();

        }

        public static int InputSales(string aValue)
        {
            int sales = -1;
            if (aValue == "Y" || aValue == "y" || aValue == "Yes" || aValue == "yes")
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter your sales amount for this period: ");
                sales = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            else if (aValue == "N" || aValue == "n" || aValue == "No" || aValue == "no")
            {
                sales = -1;
            }
            return sales;

        }

        public static double CalculatePay(int hoursWorked, double payRate, int sales)
        {
            double grossPay = hoursWorked * payRate;
            if (sales >= 0)
            {
                grossPay = grossPay +(.02*sales);
            }
            else if (hoursWorked > 40)
            {
                grossPay = grossPay + (.5*payRate) * (hoursWorked-40);
            }
            return grossPay;

        }

        public static double CalculateTax(int dependants, double grossPay)
        {
            int cutOff = 100 + (100 * dependants);
            double taxes;
            if (grossPay <= cutOff)
            {
                taxes = .15 * grossPay;
            }
            else
            {
                taxes = .15 * cutOff + .25*(grossPay-cutOff);
            }
            return taxes;
        }

        public static void DisplayOutput(double grossPay, double taxes)
        {
            double netPay = grossPay - taxes;
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Gross Pay: ".PadLeft(30, ' ') + grossPay);
            Console.WriteLine("Taxes: ".PadLeft(30, ' ') + taxes);
            Console.WriteLine("Net Pay: ".PadLeft(30, ' ') + netPay);
            Console.WriteLine();
            DrawLine();
        }

        public static void DrawLine()
        {
            Console.Write("______________________________________________");
        }

        public static void TerminateProgram()
        {
            Console.Write("Press any key to terminate the program...");
            Console.Read();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DisplayOutput needs the values to display passed into it; for example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.Clear();
        DisplayTitle();
        InputData();
        DisplayOutput(CalculatePay(40, 50, 60), CalculateTax(4, CalculatePay(40, 50, 60)));
        TerminateProgram();
    }
```